# How to Read a txt File Based On Where a Specific character is

Tags: python, discord

I Have a code that reads a file and randomly chooses a line from that file and sends it through DMs as a discord bot. However, I want it to read a certain section of the txt file by which character the section starts and ends with.
Ex:                                                                             ,
Hi
,

This is the code I'm using that reads a random line and sends it through DM:

```
emailFile = open("C:/Users/jacob/Downloads/Spotify_premiums.txt", "r")
emails = []
for email in emailFile:
    emails.append(email)

@bot.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
@commands.has_any_role("| Premium |")
async def spotifypremium(ctx):
    msg = emails
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.author, random.choice(msg))
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Alt Has Been Seen To Your DMs")
    await bot.purge_from(ctx.message.channel, limit=2)
    await bot.send_message(ctx.message.author, "Please Wait 30 Seconds Before Using This Command Again. If you do not wait the full time then you won't be sent an alt.")
```

Here's My Revision:

```
    emailFile = open("C:/Users/jacob/Downloads/Uplay_Formatted.txt", "r", 
    encoding="utf16").read()
    parse = False
    email = []
    for com in emailFile.split('\n'):
        if com.startswith(',Credentials'):
            parse = True
        elif com.startswith(',Credentials'):
            parse = False
        if parse:
            email.append(com)


    @bot.command(pass_context = True)
    @commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
    @commands.has_any_role("| Premium |")
    async def spotifypremium(ctx):
            msg = email
            await bot.send_message(ctx.message.author, random.choice(msg))
            await bot.send_message(ctx.message.channel, "Alt Has Been Seen 
    To Your DMs")
            await bot.purge_from(ctx.message.channel, limit=2)
            await bot.send_message(ctx.message.author, "Please Wait 30 
    Seconds Before Using This Command Again. If you do not wait the full 
    time then you won't be sent an alt.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use startswith() and endswith() example [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

For example, in your case; it would be something along these lines:

```
emailFile = open("C:/Users/jacob/Downloads/Spotify_premiums.txt", "r")
read_emails = emailFile.read()
emails = [com for com in read_emails.split() if com.startswith(',') and com.endswith(',')]
```

Per your requirements to display content between start and end. Try this:

```
emailFile = open("C:/Users/jacob/Downloads/Spotify_premiums.txt", "r", encoding="utf8").read()
parse = False
for com in emailFile.split('\n'):
    if com.startswith(',Credentials'):
        parse = True
    elif com.startswith(',Credentials'):
        parse = False
    if parse:
        #do stuff
```

And if you are just trying to get the email addresses from the text file.

```
import re

emailFile = open("C:/Users/jacob/Downloads/Spotify_premiums.txt", "r", encoding="utf8").read()
email = []
for com in emailFile.split():
    if re.match(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+',  com):
        email.append(com)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156401/discussion-on-answer-by-felasniper-how-to-read-a-txt-file-based-on-where-a-speci).

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

You can match lines that start with the word 'Hi' `re.match('^Hi', line)`

The ^ indicates the start of the line, and theres a few other special characters that might help.

Comment: I have a list of accounts in a txt document and there’s a comma at the end and the beginning of what I want to use, so how would I go about doing this.

Comment: how exactly is it formatted? I'd recommend reading the link I sent you.

The regex would be something like `\,[^\,]*\,`

Comment: is there a place I can send you the file?

Comment: you can send a couple of lines here?

Comment: ,Credentials - reinoud@gmail.com:gencom1c
Username - rmvaandr
2factor - False
Country - US
-----PLATFORMS-----
uplay
steam
----GAMES----
ANNO 2070 -> PC
Assassin's Creed® III -> PC
Far Cry® 3 Blood Dragon -> PC
Far Cry® 4 Мастер Арены -> ANDROID
Might and Magic Heroes VI -> PC
The Crew™ -> PC
---------------
,

Comment: Yeah so based on what i can see to match that line `\,[^,]*\,` should work. You have to use the backslashes to 'escape' the characters so they could be read as normal text since commas are special characters in regex. The part inside the square brackets means characters that are not a comma and the * means there can be any number of characters that are not commas.

Comment: and this would be put in my emailfile code correct?

Comment: again, it is hard to identify what exactly you want. So the for loop that says `for email in emailFile` basically reads each line of that file. If you only want to append the lines that start and end with a comma then you can use the regex that I showed you. `\,[^,]*\,` but I highly recommend reading the link for yourself so you can get a better understanding on how regular expressions work.